# DropdownList Selected value in textbox from Database in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have view in which I have dropdownlist box in Mvc3

When i select a item it should fire an action and give me corresponding rows depending upon the value.

These corresponding values have to be displayed in text box of the same View

I have tried the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function () { $("#Departments").change(function () { 
           var itemVal=$(this).val(); 
           $.get('@Url.Action("GetData")', 
                  { id: itemVal }, 
                  function (data) { $("#Fee").val(data); }); 
           }); 
      });
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Departments").change(function () {
           var itemVal=$(this).val();
      $.get('@Url.Action("GetData")',
                { id: itemVal }, function (data)      
     {
         $("#Fee").val(data);
     });

 });
});

Comment: But GEtdata method is not calling and Data is not postedBack.

Comment: var query = from crs in db.Courses
                        where crs.CourseID == val
                        select crs;

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the below method to fire an action while changing values in dropdownlist.

```
 $('#ShipCountry').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/GetCities",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               ....

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are are not getting value from dropdown. It should be like this:

```
var itemVal=$(this).find('option:selected').val();
```